# how can I open a flask app on my browser that's running remotely on docker?

Tags: python, docker, flask, pycharm, docker-compose

I am running a flask app using Pycharm and I get the following message:
INFO:werkzeug: * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

I have been trying to access the website from my local browser and it’s not working. First, I tried the following in Pycharm and it didn’t work: “RUN > Edit configuration > Docker deployment > Container > Add port binding > container port=5000 > host port=5000”. Is this right? should I add something in Host IP?

I also tried to access the API URL in the build, execution > docker, but it’s not working.

What is the easier way to solve this problem?

Comment: please share your docker-compose.yml

Comment: I don't have any .yml files. Do I have to? Thanks.

Comment: You tagged your question with "docker-compose"?

Answer (score 4):

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

you can provide host ip directly

requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.10.1
```

## or it can be any version

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTANER Your Name "youremail@domain.tld"
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev
#your Dockerfile is missing this line
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

docker commands to run

```
docker build -t flaskapp:latest .
#flask runs in default port 5000
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 flaskapp
```

In browser: http://localhost:5000